# Change Password of a user in /etc/shadow

Tags: password

I would like to change the password of a user in the `/etc/shadow`.
I **can't** use password changing programs like `passwd`. It must be done by editing the `/etc/shadow`. 
The `/etc/shadow` is on a mounted hard drive and chroot is not working.

For example:

```
root:$asdf.1AH.MJ3sivd4$YFoFnasdf4cZW9H6G6cbT4.1VBmasdfmv.a0wCU/i3zEFasdfasdf4W.:15843:0:99999:7:::
otheruser:$asdf.1AH.MJ3sivd4$YFoFnasdf4cZW9H6G6cbT4.1VBmasdfmv.a0wCU/i3zEFasdfasdf4W.:15843:0:99999:7:::
```

Can anybody provide me a shell script to change the password of root with `sed` or `awk` or something like that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use password changing tools?

Answer (score 29):

The easiest solution, if having an empty password is not a problem for you, is to change the `/etc/passwd` file and not the `/etc/shadow`.

An example line of the `/etc/passwd` file is:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

The 'x' in this line means that the password is actually stored hashed in the shadow file. One thing that you can do is to just remove it like this:

```
root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Then you can actually login with the username `root` and with an empty password.

If you don’t want to leave the root user’s password blank, once you’ve removed the password from root, change to root user:

```
user@machine$ su root
password: [blank]
```

Then run the command to change the root password:

```
root@machine# passwd
New password: [desired password]
Retype new password: [desired password]
```

Now you have a password for root that you know.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the mkpasswd tool to do this. There's a good primer on how to use it over on cyberciti.biz, titled: [Linux / UNIX: Generating random password with mkpasswd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/generating-random-password/).

#### Example

```
mkpasswd --char=10 --crypt-md5
```

The package is usually called `makepasswd`, but the tool is typically called `mkpasswd`.

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkpasswd) for more details.

#### Generating contents of `/etc/shadow` directly

The following python command will generate the portion that goes into the `/etc/shadow` file:

**Python**

```
$ python -c "import crypt, getpass, pwd; \
         print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$SALTsalt\$')"
```

**Perl**

```
$ perl -e 'print crypt("password","\$6\$saltsalt\$") . "\n"'
```

Which generates the following output:

```
$6$SALTsalt$UiZikbV3VeeBPsg8./Q5DAfq9aj7CVZMDU6ffBiBLgUEpxv7LMXKbcZ9JSZnYDrZQftdG319XkbLVMvWcF/Vr/
```

#### Changing the /etc/shadow

Here's a command that will change the existing entry with the newly generated password field from the command above.

```
perl -pe 's|(root):(\$.*?:)|\1:\$6\$SALTsalt\$UiZikbV3VeeBPsg8./Q5DAfq9aj7CVZMDU6ffBiBLgUEpxv7LMXKbcZ9JSZnYDrZQftdG319XkbLVMvWcF/Vr/:|' /etc/shadow > /etc/shadow.new
```

**NOTE:** This is a rough example but works. You'll need to take the results from the command that generated the hashed password, and escape the dollar signs ($) with slashes (\$).

The results are stored in a new file /etc/shadow.new. Once you've confirmed the results you can replace `/etc/shadow` with the new file, `/etc/shadow.new`.

Comment: Thank You, but I need a command to edit the string in the shadow file.

Comment: See my updates, is that what you're after?

Comment: Hello, can you also provide me a command to replace the existing password of an user in the /etc/shadow file with the generated password?

Comment: Why can't you use changing password programs? @JoelDavis asked the question as a comment on your question too. Just curious.

Comment: @slm, in my case, I don't want to login in the user's machine and leave anything in their `history` or `last` logs.

Comment: @slm thanks for the code. I don't have much knowledge about perl, can you please help to make the whole process in one line of code?

Comment: To clarify the original question:   as indicated, the /etc/shadow file is on a mounted drive, and so it is NOT /etc/shadow directly as it is.   But perhaps /mnt/etc/shadow.   And all the password tools only modify /etc/shadow file, not any other files mounted in any other directory.   Which is why all the password tools cannot be used.

Comment: @PeterTeoh - thanks, I was aware of this, that's why I showed the perl/python commands to show how to change the salted passwords directly. There isn't a direct method beyond that, except if you were to make  a link `ln -s ...` to the /etc/shadow file at the alt. location.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the password all together for the user in /etc/shadow, boot the system, login with no password, then use the passwd command. If possible, do not bring the system on the network until this is completed.

Comment: Removing the password hash in `/etc/shadow` will prevent the user from logging in with *any* password since nothing you enter can result in a hash that would match the empty string.

Comment: @n.st This advice seems to be valid to me. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11700775/870150

Comment: Also seems to be the advice over at https://askubuntu.com/a/84697/178596