# Admin privilege

Tags: permissions

I have just installed Mint 129.3. I am the only one on my computer system. I am trying to change the samba config file to rename my network. When I edit the file in terminal it will not let me save it. Says I need elevated privileges. I was under the impression that I was the sole admin on my system, I'm the only user.
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default system files are owned and protected for the root user (a special admin account).

On many Linux distributions there are special commands to run a program as root. A few examples

For terminal-based applications use `sudo`

```bsh
sudo vim your_filename.txt
```

For graphical applications it's a little more challenging

On old Ubuntu variants you may be able to use `gksu`

```bsh
gksu gedit your_filename.txt
```

Newer versions have a special prefix for accessing files as root, by putting `admin://` before the full path

```bsh
gedit admin:///path/to/your_filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You are the only user, but your account is not an admin account, which is exactly right, from the security standpoint.

The admin account is `root`, but don't log in to that account; normally you never have to, except for initial setup. To start a root shell, you need [`su`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) and the root password.

What you need to run a particular command with elevated privileges is [`sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

I don't know if Mint has `sudo` configured so that the sole user has the privilege out of the box.  If not, you'll have to [edit it and add yourself](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/sudo-and-the-sudoers-file/):

```
$ su -
# vi /etc/sudoers
# exit
$ _
```

Comment: If you don't have privilage to `sudo` and don't have the root password. Then you will have to fix it, but you can't do the above without root password. (If this is the case then we may be able to tell you which question answers this problem).

Comment: If you have physical access, you can boot from a CD or flash, `mount` the root partition, and edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` [to taste](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533599/3633).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. First of this is all new to me. I was challenged to try Mint. I have been a windows user for 30 years. This is a little hard to understand, however I will pursue this and try my best to move forward.

Comment: @Lonetree2020 Did your name change, or are you another person, talking as if your are the original poster.

Comment: I am the original Lonetree2020. I have determined that I do have sudo privileges.

Comment: You may also find https://forums.linuxmint.com/ helpful.